# горячие клавиши эксель на пайтоне

Tags: python, excel, клавиатура

В документе есть значения в ячейках с гиперссылкой, при попытке добавить в середине новую строку с методом insert_rows() (библиотека openpyxl), добавить то добавить строку, но на пустых (новых) строк остаётся гиперссылки. И соответственно гиперссылки отходят от своего прикреплённого значения.

Если документа вручную открыть и добавить самому, то всё в порядке.

Комбинация клавишей Alt + Я + ВВ + А так и делает, то есть вставить строку.
Поэтому появился идея горячими клавишами эту проблему решить.

Как на пайтоне открыть документа эксель, выбрать нужную строку и вставить горячим клавишам новую строку?